# Lambda expression group by select last with a condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

With this Code :

```
List<Transaction> list = db.Transaction
                           .GroupBy(t => t.ProcessId)
                           .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.TransactionId).FirstOrDefault())
                           .Where(t => t.xId != null && t.PAmount > 0)
                           .ToList();
```

I was trying to get the last record where `xId` is not null .. the grouping works fine .. but it gets me the last record even if `xId` is null

Any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move filtering before grouping:

```
db.Transaction
  .Where(t => t.xId != null && t.PAmount > 0)
  .GroupBy(t => t.ProcessId)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.TransactionId).FirstOrDefault())
  .ToList();
```

Thus you will get for each process latest transaction which has id and amount greater than zero. Otherwise if latest transaction has id equal to null, you will completely filter out that process transactions.

EF will generate query like

```
SELECT
    [Limit1].[TransactionId] AS [TransactionId],
    [Limit1].[xId] AS [xId],
    [Limit1].[PAmount] AS [PAmount],
    [Limit1].[ProcessId] AS [ProcessId]
    FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        [Extent1].[ProcessId] AS [ProcessId]
        FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[xId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[PAmount] > 0)
    ) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
       [Project2].[TransactionId] AS [TransactionId],
       [Project2].[xId] AS [xId],
       [Project2].[PAmount] AS [PAmount],
       [Project2].[ProcessId] AS [ProcessId]
       FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent2].[TransactionId] AS [TransactionId],
            [Extent2].[xId] AS [xId],
            [Extent2].[PAmount] AS [PAmount],
            [Extent2].[ProcessId] AS [ProcessId]
            FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[xId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[PAmount] > 0)
                   AND ([Distinct1].[ProcessId] = [Extent2].[ProcessId])
            ) AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[TransactionId] DESC
    ) AS [Limit1]
```

As you can see xId NOT NULL and PAmount > 0 conditions applied twice - first time to get distinct process ids (which have appropriate transactions). And second time when latest transaction is selected for each process.

Comment: @AmrIbrahim what do you mean by *does not work*? error?

Comment: @AmrIbrahim I have added query which is generated by EF. It's not possible that filter conditions are not applied in your case